# Removing assumptions in a geometric form of the Hahn-Banach theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Theorem(**second geometric form Hahn-Banach theorem**). Let $A⊂E$ and $B⊂E$ be two nonempty convex subsets such that $A∩B=∅$. Assume that $A$ is closed and $B$ is compact. Then there exists a closed hyperplane that strictly separates $A$ and $B$.

For example, I know that you cannot remove the convexity of the sets to be separated, but in the second form, what is the problem of removing compactness from one of the sets? More specifically, what is the problem if I remove the compactness from $B$? Is there a counterexample?

Comment: What do you mean by "strictly".  How can you separate the horizontal lineand the graph of the function $y= 1/x, x>0$ strictly. (in the plane ?)

Comment: You're going to need some constraint on $B$.  Let $B$ be the open unit disk in $\Bbb{R}^2$ and $A$ be the line $x= 1$.  These are both convex and disjoint, but are not separable.

Comment: @Tomas Strict means that it is possible to find $\varepsilon$ such that $f(x)+\varepsilon<\alpha<f(y)+\varepsilon$ for all $x\in A$ and $y \in B.$ The graph you showed is not a convex set.